# Scroll inside the console in Open Indiana

Tags: unix, console, openindiana

First time unix user here. How do I scroll and/or page the output within the console in Open Indiana?

If I list the help page for the zfs command it just outputs everything and I can't read it since it just scrolls by. I tried piping it to the less command but when I press w to scroll up it outputs a page of rows with ~.

Tried saving the ouput in a textfile with zfs -help > filename but the file shows up as empty in vim.

I'm running within Vbox and are logged on locally.

Comment: have you tried pageup?

Comment: Yes, the last line after listing the zfs help says (END) and every button I press results in the console printing a full screen which is empty except one ~ at the beginning of each row. And the prompt says (END) just as before. Pressing h/H brings upp the less help screen and q quits so some command work, not just scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a VT (Virtual Terminal), you can usually scroll with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

If you're in a GUI, there should be a scrollbar, or you can try the same key combination.

In either environment, you can pipe the command to `less`, like so:

`zfs | less`

Within `less`, you can use <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd> just as you'd expect.  <kbd>Q</kbd> will quit.  I'd suggest learning `less`, as it has many advanced features.  For example, you can forward-search with <kbd>/</kbd> and reverse-search with <kbd>?</kbd>.

`man less` for more information.

Comment: Thanks, something is wonky. If I scroll down by using e or z I can scroll up again (when I bring up the less help screen it pauses showing one screen at a time, so I am able to use e or z) to the point from where I scrolled down, but not further up. But if the console just lists something I can't scoll up again.

Comment: Tried ctrl+pgup/down and the other less commands but it did not work either. Can I attribute this to running within vbox or could it be a configuration matter?

Comment: Ctrl+pgup/down aren't less commands, just pgup/down are.  The Ctrl sequences are for VTs (i.e. console outside of GUI).